# Does '\centerline' really define '\ERROR' in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, center

In a `.tex` file, there is `\centerline{\bf A SHORT \error STORY}`, which will cause error as

```
l.3 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
                                         
? 
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \bf A SHORT \ERROR 
                              STORY
\centerline #1->\line {\hss #1
                              \hss }
l.3 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
```

The explaination by **The TeXbook** is

> A control sequence like \centerline might well define a control sequence like \ERROR before telling TEX to look at #1. Therefore TEX doesn’t interpret control sequences when it scans an argument.

It is a difficult to understand. The meaning of this sentence seems to be that because
`\centerline` defines `\ERROR`, `\centerline` will not interprete `\ERROR`, so an error is reported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `\ERROR` is not defined (which is why it generates an error)

The point of the comment is that the error is raised when the command is used not when the argument is scanned.

So
*if* `\centerline` was defined not to use its argument

```
\def\centerline#1{oops}
\centerline{....\ERROR}
```

is not an error, and similarly *if* `\centerline` locally defined `\ERROR`

```
\def\centerline#1{{\def\ERROR{OK}#1}}
\centerline{....\ERROR}
```

is not an error.

But the actual definition does give an error

```
\centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}`
```

but the context is not

```
\centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR
                              STORY}
```

as the error is not raised when the argument is scanned, it is

```
<argument> \bf A SHORT \ERROR 
                              STORY
\centerline #1->\line {\hss #1
                              \hss }
l.3 \centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
```

as the error is detexted after `\centerline` has scanned the whole argument and started processing its replacement text.

Comment: So, the used command must be defined before?

Comment: @Y.zeng well yes any command must be defined before it is expanded, but not necessarily before it is used in the argument of anither command.

Comment: But why did Mr. Knuth say that, which is not right?

Comment: @Y.zeng  the text you quote from the texbook is correct, as I tried to show in this answer.

Comment: the statment " `\centerline` _might_ ... "  means some person, somewhere _might_ define `\centerline` so that it defines `\ERROR` (eg _I_ define it that way above)  It does not mean that the definition in plain tex does that. @Y.zeng

Comment: Actually, as TeX didn't define that control sequence, so it didn't interpret it, witch has nothing about whether another control sequence defined it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149676/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-y-zeng).